# When changing the constraint layout on a textview, the text do not follow the animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make an animation on a textview, when it gets pressed.

The textview expands to fill the screen, at the top.

The following two pictures show my textview before and after pressed.

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djyfb.png)

[Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hayXj.png)

As you can see, the text jumps down when changing the constraint layout (Doing the animation).

The red dot, a drawable in the textView follows as it should, but the text behaves wrong. I have attached the the animation code, that the onclick method calls. It changes the constraints in the textview.

Note:
mapsContainer is the container witch contains the google map and menubar. 
searchDummmy is the Textview.

guidelineText is a line, to set the height of the searchdummy.

```
private void animateSearchDummy() {

    searchDummyConsttraints.clone((ConstraintLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapsContainer));

    AutoTransition t = new AutoTransition();
    t.setDuration(5000);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ConstraintLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapsContainer), t);

    searchDummyConsttraints.clear(R.id.searchDummy);

    searchDummyConsttraints.constrainHeight(R.id.searchDummy, 0);
    searchDummyConsttraints.connect(R.id.searchDummy, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.guidelineTest, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    searchDummyConsttraints.connect(R.id.searchDummy, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.mapsContainer, ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
    searchDummyConsttraints.connect(R.id.searchDummy, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.mapsContainer, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
    searchDummyConsttraints.connect(R.id.searchDummy, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.mapsContainer, ConstraintSet.TOP,0);

    searchDummyConsttraints.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.mapsContainer)); 
}
```

The xml file for the view is also attached.

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context="dtu.group.studyroom.MapsFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchDummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textviewborder"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType=""
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Find a study room"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineTest"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="119dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have spend 4 days trying to solve this problem, but without any luck so far.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue, any solution?

Comment: i have try to change the transition: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/package-summary  but without any luck....same issue!